# Neo4j Bulk Import for Windows

Tags: windows, neo4j, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I am running Neo4j 2.0.2 on a Windows 2012 server and have a need to import hundreds of millions of nodes/relationships quickly (a day). Are there any bulk import tools or processes that can be used on windows?  I have attempted to load multiple create statements using the spreadsheet method discussed on Neo4j's site but found that the statements just hang if I try to run more than 1000 statements at a time.

Comment: Are you doing a fresh load every day or are you adding hundreds of millions of nodes/relationships each day?

Comment: This is a fresh load to create an example database so I can prove out some use cases.  Going forward I can see a bulk loader being useful to do an initial population of a database but don't expect to perform these types of loads regularly.

Answer (score 0):

For high performant initial data population the best way is to use the [batch inserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html). This requires either some Java coding or use [@mesiiri's tool](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) to run batch inserter directly on csv files.

Also be sure to read his excellent blog post on http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/

Comment: @mesiiri's tool is exactly what I'm looking for.  Where do you run the code?

Comment: `batch-import` requires java and maven to be run. It generates the graph-db directory contents for you. When done you can run your neo4j server based on that directory.

Comment: I have downloaded maven.  Does the bulk importer files need to be in the maven directory?  Their example execution line is mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer" -Dexec.args="neo4j/data/graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv"  For this do you need to be at a command line in the maven directory?  If so, the csv files will also need to be in the same directory?  I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: No need to extract bulk importer inside maven directory. Put it anywhere locally, open a console for that directory and run the `mvn` command. For the csv files you can specify paths as well.